# The same output for Rock, Paper, Scissors Program

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
import random
import sys

print('ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS')

#these variables keep track of the number of wins, losses, and ties
wins = 0
losses = 0
ties = 0

while True:  #The main game loop.
    print('%s Wins, %s Losses, %s Ties' %(wins, losses, ties))
    while True: #player input loop
        print('Enter your move: (r)ock (p)aper (s)cissors or (q)uit')
        playerMove = input()
        if playerMove == 'q':
            sys.exit
        if playerMove == 'r' or playerMove == 'p' or playerMove == 's':
            break
        print('Type one of r, p, s or q.')

    #Display what the player chooses;
    if playerMove == 'r':
        print('ROCK versus ....')
    elif playerMove == 'p':
        print('PAPER versus ....')
    elif playerMove == 's':
        print('SCISSORS versus ...')

    #Display what the computer chose;
    randomNumber = random.randint(1,3)
    if randomNumber == 1:
        computerMove = 'r'
        print('ROCK')
    elif randomNumber == 2:
        computerMove = 'p'
        print('PAPER')
    elif randomNumber == 3:
        computerMove = 's'
        print("SCISSORS")

    #Display and record the win/loss/tie
    if playerMove == computerMove:
        print('It is a tie!')
        ties = ties + 1
    elif playerMove == 'r' and computerMove == 's':
        print('You win!')
        wins = wins + 1
    elif playerMove == 'p' and computerMove == 'r':
        print('You win')
        wins = wins + 1
    elif playerMove == 's' and computerMove == 'p':
        print('You win')
        wins = wins + 1
    elif playerMove == 'r' and computerMove == 'p':
        print('You lose')
        losses = losses + 1
    elif playerMove == 'p' and computerMove == 's':
        print('You lose')
        losses = losses + 1
    elif playerMove == 's' and computerMove == 'r':
        print('You lose')
        losses = losses + 1
```

The code above is a program for a Rock, Paper, Scissors game.

The code prompts an input as seen below

```
Type one of r, p, s or q.
```

```
Enter your move: (r)ock (p)aper (s)cissors or (q)uit
```

But the output does not correspond to this:

```
2 Wins, 0 Losses, 1 Ties
```

but repeatedly returns this

```
ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS
```

```
0 Wins, 0 Losses, 0 Ties
```

I ran the program using vscode with expected output on the terminal is this

```
2 Wins, 0 Losses, 1 Ties
```

but the output is this:

```
0 Wins, 0 Losses, 0 Ties
```

even after typing the right input of 'r', 'p', 's' or 'q' at the prompt

```
Type one of r, p, s or q.

Enter your move: (r)ock (p)aper (s)cissors or (q)uit
```

Comment: Other than the typo with `sys.exit` your code appears to work. Which input/computer combination (e.g. rock vs. paper) do you think is being scored incorrectly? You could streamline the logic a bit. If it isn't a tie and isn't a win then it must be a loss. Handle that with a single `else` rather than 3 different cases.

Answer (score 3):

You forget to put parentheses`()` after `sys.exit`

```
if playerMove == 'q':
     sys.exit()
```

A suggestion is change

```
# Display what the computer chose;
randomNumber = random.randint(1, 3)
if randomNumber == 1:
    computerMove = 'r'
    print('ROCK')
elif randomNumber == 2:
    computerMove = 'p'
    print('PAPER')
elif randomNumber == 3:
    computerMove = 's'
    print("SCISSORS")
```

#### TO

```
# Display what the computer chose;
computerMove = random.choice(["ROCK", "PAPER", "SCISSORS"]) # This will randomly choose one.

print(computerMove) # print computer move
# overwrite the move to the first latter of choice and lower it
computerMove = computerMove[0].lower() 
# This will change "ROCK" to "r", "PAPER" to "p" and "SCISSORS" to "s"
```